# Will my App Store updated app pick up existing data from my 8 year old app on user's devices?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, migration

I released an app to the App Store in October 2013.  I have finally updated it, adding a lot more fields to capture data and images, etc.  Three of the initial fields remain the same from the original app.  When I release the updated app, how can I tell if the old stored data will migrate into the new app?  Is there some way I can test this beforehand?  When I test the updated version on my own iPhone, the data from the original app does not move across, and both versions of the app exist independently on my phone.

Comment: If both version exist, it seems you accidentally change the bundle ID

Comment: Thank you, that was correct